# How to remove values after special character in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am having a hive table with column state as

```
**state**
taxes, TX
Washington, WA
New York, NY
New Jersey, NJ
```

Now I want to separate the state column and I want to write it in new columns as

```
**state**             **code**
taxes                   TX
Washington              WA
New York                NY
New Jersey              NJ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  split(state,',')[0]         as state
       ,ltrim(split(state,',')[1])  as code

from    mytable
```

---

```
+------------+------+
|   state    | code |
+------------+------+
| taxes      | TX   |
| Washington | WA   |
| New York   | NY   |
| New Jersey | NJ   |
+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

select   substr (name,0,instr(name,',')-1), substr (name ,instr(name,',')+1,10) from aa